# How do I use an integer programmed mathematical modelling of TSP (travelling salesman problem)?

Tags: notation, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming

Okay, so I just finished my mathematical modelling of TSP using integer programming.

Now, how do I use it?

[image]

Now, I just want to know to use this model to solve a simple 5 vertices large graph.

You don't have to use any mathematical symbols, just answer in simple plain English.

This is what I suppose I have to do:

---

Go through all combinations, and for each combination check whether it violates any constraints, if it doesn't note down the value, if the value is less than the previous noted value, then this is our new lowest route value, else we simply move on, because the former route was less than our current one.

Comment: Don't forget that all $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$.  You should be able to use any integer linear programming solver.

Comment: I would like to do it by hand, that is why the it's a simple graph consisting of 5 vertices. By the way, what integer linear pogramming solver is suitable for my need?

Comment: BTW you don't want to include $S = V$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What do you mean? Where did I do that?

Comment: Depends on convention. $S \subset V$ sometimes includes $S=V$, sometimes not.  In this case it should be not.